# CSS Best Practices: DRY

Tags: html, css, frontend

Is it considered bad practice if I repeat some styles in two different css files?
I have an about css with this code:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

and I have another page contact.css which has some repeated rules from about.css

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I can link the about.css to the contact, but it doesn't seem right to have a contact.html with a css linked about.css is this bad practice or not?

Comment: this question is more a "style" question than a real technical problem. That being said you should check out how to import other files into css files with @import.

Answer (score -1):

I usually have a base CSS file where I know certain elements will be consistent across the site such as h1, h2, h3, p, a. I will then reference this CSS on every page. That way I'm confident that the basic structure for each element is correct. Then I will make changes within the individual CSS files such as contact.css & about.css